# Solving a square sequence limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've started learning sequences and I'm having a hard time calculating the following:

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}{\sqrt[n]{3^n + 7^n}}$$

Using Heine’s Lemma I'm trying to solve it analogous to the corresponding limit definitions for functions, but I get stuck every direction I go.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One may factor $7^n$ under the $n$th root and then use some common facts.

Comment: not "possible", it is a duplicate.

Comment: yes, thanks, it's exactly the same.

Comment: where are the  squares in the  sequence?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Factor $7^n$ out of the sum underneath the radical. Then simplify (you may find the fact that $0\leq\frac37\leq1$ useful (if you prefer to avoid l'Hopital).

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(3^n+7^n)^\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}7(1+(\frac 37)^n)^\frac1n=7\cdot 1^0=7$